# why i cant bind gridview directly from ListItemCollection Object?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to SharePoint List and i need to bind gridview using list item collection object like below

```
SPList splEmployees = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Employees"];
spgvEmployees.DataSource = splEmployees.Items;//or splEmployees.GetItems();
spgvEmployees.DataBind();
```

this is not success when i bind it to gridview contains Title and EmployeeID columns but it success when i remove EmployeeID column.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a SPDataSource instead.

```
SPDataSource myDatas = new SPDataSource();
myDatas.List = splEmployees;
spgvEmployees.DataSource=myDatas;
spgvEmployees.DataBind();
```